# Which JBoss 5.1 libraries I need for a standalone EJB client?

Tags: jboss, ejb

I'm migrating from JBossAS 4.05 to JBoss 5.1, and I have doubt about wich libraries I need to change in my EJB standalone clients.

From JBossAS 4.0.5, I have a straight list of libraries that I need to deploy within all clients. But, in 5.1 version, some libraries was changed or supressed.

Anybody have a straight list just for access remote EJB services?

Answer (score 0):

As per ...
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/ch01.html#d0e525

> 1.5.3. jbossall-client.jar   The client/jbossall-client.jar library
>   that used to bundle the majority of
>   jboss client libraries, is now
>   referencing them instead through the
>   Class-Path manifest entry. This allows
>   swapping included libraries (e.g.
>   jboss-javaee.jar) without having to
>   re-package jbossall-client.jar. On the
>   other hand, it requires that you have
>   jbossall-client.jar together with the
>   other client/*.jar libraries, so they
>   can be found.

Look at [this post](http://devgrok.blogspot.com/2010/02/building-your-own-jbossall-clientjar.html) for a solution to:

> The newer versions of JBoss (I'm using
>   5.1.0 GA) very annoyingly have all the client jars split into at least 47
>   separate jars! Which is a bit rude
>   when you consider the total number of
>   jars they expect you to copy into your
>   tomcat/lib dir is a whopping 93.

Comment: In the standalone OS, I not want to add any dependency with a JBoss instance. I want just libraries embedded within my standalone client. The file jbossall-client.jar, in recent versions, was reduced and contains just basic classes, excluding serialization, remote and other necessary classes.

Thanks,

And

Comment: Ok. But, if I put all jboss* files in one, we are back to 4.* and weblogic.jar libraries model, with more then 30MB under one jar file. My expectations are a clean deployable application file, with a straight as possible classpath.

I'm trying to add/remove *.jar files from classpath ... sometime, the path will work. I'll publish the results here ...

Thanks,

And