# JBoss Client directory

Tags: jboss

I recently started learning more about JBoss Application sever. After installation I was looking inside all directories created by JBoss installation. (I'm using JBoss AS version - jboss-5.0.1.GA)

I referred documentation available at this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html)

It says 'client' directory contains Jar files needed by remote clients.

```
  client:   The JARs that are required for clients that run outside of JBoss are located in the client directory.
```

When I looked inside 'client' directory after installation, it contains 90 jar files overall. Does that mean If I create a remote ejb client I would need to include all the 90 jars in my remote application classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `JBoss AS 5.x` things got complicated.

Placing all of the client jar files on classpath will certainly work.
In `JBoss 4.x` there was an option to use `jbossall-client.jar` which integrated other numerous client libs into single file. If you'll look into same named jar in JBoss 5.x you'll find out that it's reduced to manifest referencing other jars. Placing this single jar in your classpath will work as long as all of the jars referenced by manifest are present in the same directory.

If accessing remote EJB is all you need then only a subset of jars is required, unfortunatelly it's hard to tell which ones is it.
Following [this coderanch link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/454071/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/javax-naming-Reference-cast-org) (I've found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133031/which-jboss-5-1-libraries-i-need-for-a-standalone-ejb-client) on SO) you'll find such subset prepared for `JBoss 5.1.0.GA`.
Be warned though, list of jars published on coderanch has abbreviated names, some misquotations and at least two jars are not present in server version 5.0.1. If reducing number of dependencies is your priority, use this list wisely and enhance/extend it by trials and errors.