# Reference EJBs outside the Application server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I would like to know if any of you have ever call an EJB remotely. This is my scenario:

I have a single remote interface package in its own jar file. Then there is a EJB module (another jar file) that depends on the previous one to implement the interface as a @Stateless session bean.

I have deployed the EJB module in JBOSS 5.1.0.GA. When I try calling the EJB from within Eclipse, the returned object is not recognized as being of the interface type. Below are the differents java codes.

The Business interface:

```cs
@Remote
public interface RemoteBusinessInterface
{
 public CustomerResponse getCustomerData( final CustomerRequest customerRequest );
}
```

Implementing class package in its own jar file:

```cs
@Stateless
public class RemoteEJBBean implements RemoteBusinessInterface
{

   public CustomerResponse getCustomerData( final CustomerRequest customerRequest )
{...
```

And The code calling the remote EJB:

```cs
public class TestRemoteEjb
{

public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Object ref = initialContext.lookup( "java:/CustomerServiceBean/remote" );
        System.out.println( ref );
        if ( ref instanceof RemoteBusinessInterface )
        {
            System.out.println( "RemoteBusinessInterface" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "Not of type RemoteBusinessInterface" );
        }

    }
    catch ( NamingException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The output reads:

Reference Class Name: Proxy for: com.tchouaffe.remote.interfaces.RemoteBusinessInterface
Type: ProxyFactoryKey
Content: ProxyFactory/remote-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/CustomerServiceBean/CustomerServiceBean/remote
Type: EJB Container Name
Content: jboss.j2ee:jar=remote-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CustomerServiceBean,service=EJB3
Type: Proxy Factory is Local
Content: false
Type: Remote Business Interface
Content: com.tchouaffe.remote.interfaces.RemoteBusinessInterface
Type: Remoting Host URL
Content: socket://127.0.0.1:3873/

Not of type RemoteBusinessInterface

I have been wondering why the returned object is of a type other than RemoteBusinessInterface.

Thanks for any help.

Edmond

Comment: if you cast the lookup result to RemoteBusinessInterface you get an Exception, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Any attempt to cast the result to RemoteBusinessInterface does throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the following point:

It seems to be that you are not initializing the [InitialContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/context.html) object.
According to JBoss 5 [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Contexts-Obtaining_a_Context_using_InitialContext.html) the properties needed are:

> Properties env = new Properties();
>   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.NamingContextFactory");
>   env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
>   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");
>   InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);

Additionaly, try to check if your client code has the necessary dependencies. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/ch01.html#d0e525) is not clear enough about what are the jar files, but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133031/which-jboss-5-1-libraries-i-need-for-a-standalone-ejb-client) can help you to identify them. You also need to include the jar with the remote interface.